# Is there a way to render "material preview", as seen in the main layout (viewport)?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Is there a way to render "material preview", as seen in the main layout (viewport), outside of a screen capture software, which is causing issues for me?

Answer (score 5):

You can render directly from any viewport using the "Viewport Render" option:

[image: Viewport]

Be sure to set the color management to Standard when rendering this way. Otherwise, the exported image will be run through filmic twice resulting in gray highlights.